# SUM of count with case and when

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT U.id, MONTHNAME(Meeting.created_at) as MonthName,
       (CASE WHEN count(U.id) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as newUser,
       (CASE WHEN count(U.id) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as oldUser
FROM  mms_meetings AS Meeting
JOIN mms_meeting_users AS MU ON MU.meeting_id = Meeting.id
JOIN mms_users AS U ON U.id = MU.user_id
GROUP BY U.id, MONTHNAME(Meeting.created_at)
```

**My result is**

```
- id MonthName newUser oldUser

 - 276  August  0   1
 - 334  August  1   0
 - 616  August  1   0
 - 729  August  1   0
 - 887  August  1   0
 - 964  August  1   0
 - 992  August  1   0
```

Now i want sum of new and old records with monthname only so i changed this query to like this

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Meeting.created_at) as MonthName,
sum(CASE WHEN count(U.id) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as newUser,
sum(CASE WHEN count(U.id) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as oldUser
FROM  mms_meetings AS Meeting
JOIN mms_meeting_users AS MU ON MU.meeting_id = Meeting.id
JOIN mms_users AS U ON U.id = MU.user_id
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Meeting.created_at)
```

its showing error [Err] 1111 - `Invalid use of group function`

can anyone help me with that. 
i want result like

**i want result like**

```
- MonthName newUser oldUser

 - August   6   1
 - September 45 4
 - October 3    1
```

Comment: can you edit your question with data

Comment: Cannot get the exact question as the relationships are not clear. you can try this query though:  select MonthName,sum(new),sum(old) from (SELECT MONTHNAME(Meeting.created_at) as MonthName,
(CASE WHEN count(U.id) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as new,
(CASE WHEN count(U.id) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as old
FROM  mms_meetings AS Meeting
JOIN mms_meeting_users AS MU ON MU.meeting_id = Meeting.id
JOIN mms_users AS U ON U.id = MU.user_id
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Meeting.created_at)) as set1
group by set1.MonthName

Comment: didn't get your point. is it not in readable format ?

Comment: It is readable, but the column and table relations are not clear as you have give only two queries to look at.

Comment: not working this is giving me same result as `SELECT MONTHNAME(Meeting.created_at) as MonthName,
(CASE WHEN count(U.id) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as new,
(CASE WHEN count(U.id) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as old
FROM  mms_meetings AS Meeting
JOIN mms_meeting_users AS MU ON MU.meeting_id = Meeting.id
JOIN mms_users AS U ON U.id = MU.user_id
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Meeting.created_at)` this query is giving